# Do dependent variable essentially means the same thing as independent variable?

Tags: terminology

Or both of them are different things?

PS- I've encountered it while reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_and_independent_variables#Statistics).

Comment: From the top of the wiki page: "A symbol that stands for an arbitrary input is called an independent variable, while a symbol that stands for an arbitrary output is called a dependent variable." So not the same thing at all. Two different things.

Comment: Question is not about independent variable v/s dependent variable it is about independent variable v/s depending variable.

Comment: I see the term "depending variable" occurs exactly once on that page. The paragraph it occurs in is not even written in grammatical English. There may be multiple errors in that paragraph; that sort of thing happens sometimes in Wikipedia.

Comment: "Depending variable" is ungrammatical. It's the same thing as "dependent variable," just written incorrectly.